# Convertir Json a Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, pandas

Tengo el siguiente Json

```
[{
  "documentosVinculados": [
    {
      "fechaCreacion": "2018-05-08T15:56:51-03:00",
      "fechavinculacionDefinitiva": "2018-05-08T15:56:51-03:00",
      "numeroDocumento": "PT-2018-21487012",
      "referencia": "P",
      "tipodeDocumento": "PY",
      "usuarioAsociacion": "Pedro",
      "usuarioGenerador": "Pedro"
    },
    {
      "fechaCreacion": "2018-05-08T15:55:49-03:00",
      "fechavinculacionDefinitiva": "2018-05-08T15:56:11-03:00",
      "numeroDocumento": "2018-TT-YY",
      "referencia": "notificación",
      "tipodeDocumento": "OP",
      "usuarioAsociacion": "Pablo",
      "usuarioGenerador": "Pablo"
    }
  ],
  "historialOperacion": [
    {
      "destinatario": "PRES",
      "destinoCodigoReparticion": "DAT",
      "destinoCodigoSector": "PRES",
      "destinoDescripcionReparticion": "PRES",
      "destinoDescripcionSector": "Sector A",
      "estado": "Vacio",
      "expediente": "EX458855252",
      "fechaOperacion": "2018-05-08T15:56:51-03:00",
      "idExpediente": 986332,
      "motivo": "vinculación de notificación",
      "origenCodigoReparticion": "AA",
      "origenCodigoSector": "PRE",
      "origenDescripcionReparticion": "Dirección",
      "origenDescripcionSector": "Dirección",
      "tipoOperacion": "Pase",
      "usuario": "Pablo"
    },
    {
      "destinatario": "Pablo",
      "destinoCodigoReparticion": "DG",
      "destinoCodigoSector": "AA",
      "estado": "Tramitación",
      "expediente": "EX558966",
      "fechaOperacion": "2018-05-08T15:54:45-03:00",
      "idExpediente": 89633,
      "motivo": "Adquisición",
      "origenCodigoReparticion": "DG",
      "origenCodigoSector": "PRE",
      "tipoOperacion": "Adquisición",
      "usuario": "Raul"
    },
    {
      "destinatario": "DVAR",
      "destinoCodigoReparticion": "DGTT",
      "destinoCodigoSector": "PRET",
      "destinoDescripcionReparticion": "Dirección",
      "destinoDescripcionSector": "Pres",
      "estado": "Tramitación",
      "expediente": "EX201720",
      "fechaOperacion": "2018-04-17T12:51:31-03:00",
      "idExpediente": 85966,
      "motivo": "se adjunto nota",
      "origenCodigoReparticion": "DGPP",
      "origenCodigoSector": "PRE",
      "origenDescripcionReparticion": "Dirección",
      "origenDescripcionSector": "PRE",
      "tipoOperacion": "Pase",
      "usuario": "Carlos"
    }
  ]
}]
```

Necesitaría tomar solo lo que esta dentro de **historialOperacion** y convertirlo a una vista de tabla, estuve probando opciones que da panda pero en todas tengo errores como por ejemplo ejecutando

```
print(json_normalize(data['historialDeOperacion']))
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Esto `print(json_normalize(data[0]['historialOperacion']))` puede ser?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho obtengo el mismo error    ***print(json_normalize(data[0]['historialOperacion']))
TypeError: string indices must be integers***

Comment: Raro acabo de probarlo con tu ejemplo y no me da ningún error: https://repl.it/@pmoracho/jsonnormalize

Comment: Fijate además que no es `historialDeOperacion` sino `historialOperacion`

Comment: Si perfecto funciona, podrías agregarlo como respuesta asi lo puedo calificar, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dos observaciones:

- Tienes un problema tipográfico, la clave del diccionario es `historialOperacion` en vez de `historialDeOperacion`.
- Por otro lado, el objeto base es una lista, aparentemente con un solo elemento que es un diccionario, por lo que en principio deberías acceder así: `data[0]` para indicar justamente el primer ítem de la lista.

  ```
  print(json_normalize(data[0]['historialOperacion']))
  ```

  Eventualmente si tuvieras más de un elemento en esta lista deberías hacer un ciclo para recorrer cada uno de estos, por ejemplo:

  ```
  for e in data:
     print(json_normalize(e['historialOperacion']))
  ```